# Can anyone recognize the pattern through which this list is sorted and recommend an algorithm for that?

Tags: algorithm

I have a list like this :

```
my_list = ['A','AC','F','AB','ADF','D','DF','C','B]
```

I want to find an algorithm to sort the list as this :

```
sorted_list = ['A','C','AC','B','AB','F','D','DF','ADF']
```

I wonder if anyone who is able to recognize the pattern could recommend me a recognized algorithm to solve this kind of problem. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have more examples? That would help to identify an algorithm that will also work as expected on other cases.

Answer (score 1):

The only rule I can see is that a single letter has to appear first before it can appear in a longer string.

If all the string are nodes and each single letter has a (directed) edge from it to all the strings that contain it then you end up with topological sort. But then there would be a lot of other solutions. E.g. A, B, C, D, F, AB, AC, ADF, DF would be valid too.

It could also be that all strings have an edge to all others containing it (or its characters). This would force that ADF is after DF.

Answer (score 1):

I had noticed another pattern here,

step1: look from left to right and spot the first string that has more than one letter

step 2: put all possible combinations that had appeared in the first list of the found string (from step 1) and than the string itself.

step 3: redo step 1 for the next more than two latter string and insert only combination that had not appeared yet.

this is only based on one example so I cant be sure that this is the correct pattern but it works for this example.

Answer (score 1):

The target sorted list is this:

['A', 'C', 'AC', 'B', 'AB', 'F', 'D', 'DF', 'ADF']

But let us assume this is also possible:

['A', 'B', 'AB', 'C', 'AC', 'D', 'F', 'DF', 'ADF']

It feels even more sorted. And it becomes easier to find a creation pattern. We first order the original list lexicographically:

['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'AB', 'AC', 'DF', 'ADF']

We then scan the list sequentially from the left, looking for words to move to the left according to some criterion we define. For example, we find that 'AB' contains letters present to its left.

[A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', '**AB**', 'AC', 'DF', 'ADF']

Therefore, we move it to the left as far as possible without bypassing any word with any of those letters.

[A', 'B', '**AB**', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'AC', 'DF', 'ADF']

And so on. It becomes up to the OP to decide whether the target sorted list is carved in stone or maybe just one of several equally possible outcomes from the unknown generation algorithm.